# What is the difference between SPIFFS and EEPROM?

Tags: esp8266, flash-memory

I would like to store some data in esp8266. There are two ways SPIFFS and EEPROM. I can not decide which one to use as both of them saves data. I also read that 
both SPIFFS and EEPROM are part of Flash drive. So does that mean hardware for both of them is same?

Answer (score 6):

**SPIFFS** (Serial Peripheral Interface Flash File System) is a method for creating a file system in NOR-type flash memory.

**EEPROM** (Electrically Erasable Programmable Read-Only Memory) is a type of non-volatile memory, floating-gate transistors.

You can use either.

Comment: Thanks @matsk But it says that in esp8266 both SPIFFS and EEPROM  are part of Flash drive. So does that mean hardware for both of them is same?

Comment: If you refer to something, please include an URL.

Comment: This is the [link](http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.0.0/doc/filesystem.html).

Comment: This [link](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33501/eeprom-put-and-get-not-working-on-esp8266-nodemcu) also says that EEPROM is emulated using Flash drive

Comment: Your question was about the differences SPIFFS and EEPROM, and now you are commenting about how the code handles the different technologies. In short, EEPROM and FLASH are keeping the data during the loss of power = non-volatile memory.